# How do I connect to a computer using IP address?

Tags: remote-access

How do I connect to a computer using IP address. I connected to a computer using team viewer recently.
I cannot do that anymore and would like to use IP address of that pc

Answer (score 0):

You can use Remote Desktop Connection to connect to remote server using IP. click on start and run mstsc.

Please remember that you need to enable remote access on that server.